# Azure Logic App how to read files from ADLS using HTTP GET

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use an HTTP get to iterate through a folder in ADLS. The folder "
TemplatesUpdated" has a bunch of subfolders that have a few files in each subfolder. I want to iterate through each subfolder and then copy each file to a new location. This is what I have so far, but I am not sure what to put in the Body to get each subfolder and each item within the subfolders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Achieving your requirement using HTTP requires methods in order to iterate or loop through each folder. There are 2 ways of achieving your requirement.

**WAY - 1:** *USING LOGIC APPS WITH AZURE BLOB STORAGE CONNECTOR*

You will require 2 List Blob actions so that one will get the subfolders in `TemplatesUpdated` and the other List Blob retrieves files n the subfolder. below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

**WAY - 2:** *USING SDK*

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>"
SAS_TOKEN='<SAS TOKEN>'

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

containers = blob_service.list_containers()
for c in containers:
    generator = blob_service.list_blobs(c.name)
    for blob in generator:
        print("\t Blob name: "+c.name+'/'+  blob.name)
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this without using the list blobs? like can i get folder names using http get? theres some firewall issues with the storage account that block the logic apps from using any of the azure blob storage actions

Comment: You can use Listing blob using HTTP connector. For more information you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs you can replace List blob with HTTP connector

Comment: @J.Doe Also, try taking python into consideration which will be working fine.